# Glassfish 3.1.2.2: @WebServiceProvider deployment fails: DPL5041 : Unknown port-component-name

Tags: web-services, glassfish, deploying, service-provider

I am having problems to get a @WebServiceProvider web service deployed in Glassfish 3.1.2.

I configured the glassfish-ejb-jar.xml the following way for my service.

```
<ejb>
  <ejb-name>TestWebService</ejb-name>
  <webservice-endpoint>
    <port-component-name>TestWebService</port-component-name>
    <endpoint-address-uri>HEAD/TestWebService</endpoint-address-uri>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </webservice-endpoint>
</ejb>
```

The web service is implemented as follows.

```
package test.ws.services;

import [...left out for brevity...]

@WebServiceProvider(
  targetNamespace = "http://ws.test.com"
  , serviceName = "HEAD/TestWebService"
  , portName = "TestServicePort")
@ServiceMode(value = Service.Mode.PAYLOAD)
@Stateless
@HandlerChain(file = "test_handlers.xml")
@Interceptors({ TestInterceptor.class })
public class TestWebService implements Provider<Source> {

  @WebMethod
  public Source invoke(Source request) {
    return calcResponseSource(request);
  }

}
```

When starting the glassfish server the following error is shown in the glassfish server.log.

```
 SEVERE  javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common DPL5041:Unknown port-component-name TestWebServiceService port, all sub elements will be ignored
 WARNING javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common DPL8007: Unsupported deployment descriptors element endpoint-address-uri value HEAD/TestWebService
 WARNING javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common DPL8007: Unsupported deployment descriptors element transport-guarantee value NONE
```

Later on the service gets deployed at a "technical" URL showing the fully qualified class name.

```
 INFO javax.enterprise.webservices.org.glassfish.webservices WS00019: EJB Endpoint deployed
      server  listening at address at http://test:10280/HEAD/TestWebService/test.ws.services.TestWebService
```

I searched the web, but could not find any solution for setting up the glassfish server to do a deployment without errors.

PS: This problem also seems to stop me from enabling HTTPS for the web service.

Regards
Egbert

Comment: Did you ever get this issue resolved?